# What is the present-day connotation of 'Tunte'?

Tags: meaning, connotation, curiosity

Among similar examples, it is common for Anglophone gays to use words that originally had more vitriolic connotations, e.g., 'queer,' sometimes 'dyke,' and to a lesser extent 'fag,' as communal identifiers. I am led to understand that a something similar has happened to 'Tunte,' though my more-fluent friends can't elucidate to what extent this is the case. In what situations would this word be used in present-day Germany?

Comment: A *Tunte* is a man who dresses up as a woman, or behaves touchy-feely to other men, in public. This doesn't include gay couples.

Comment: I would use the word for a gay moving, talking (and perhaps dressing) like a woman in a more or less exaggerated way. When a hetero man tries to imitate a gay, he will mostly do it 'tuntig', like a 'Tunte'. I don't know if today the word is used  offensively. For me 'Schwuchtel' would be offensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be differences across various demographics, but in general, I think that the closest equivalent in English would be *queen* -- at least as far as meaning is concerned.

Wikipedia seems to think so, too:

> Mit dem meist abschätzigen Begriff Tunte werden sowohl in manchen
>   heterosexuellen als auch homosexuellen Kreisen oft solche Schwule
>   bezeichnet, die durch ein affektiertes Verhalten auffallen. [...]
>   Besonders in der Selbstbezeichnung unter Schwulen muss es jedoch nicht
>   in jedem Fall negativ gemeint sein. <sup>[German Wikipedia "Tunte"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunte)</sup>
>
> In gay slang, queen is a term used to refer to flamboyant or
>   effeminate gay man. The term can either be pejorative or celebrated as
>   a type of self-identification.<sup>[English Wikpedia "Queen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_(slang))</sup>

Note, however, that there are subtle differences. "Tunte" originally denoted a dowdy kind of woman or an old spinster -- so a much less glamorous derivation than the English "Queen".

**Usage** is even more different. The German "Tunte" is much less affectionate and tends much stronger towards pejorative use than the English "Queen".

As always with slang: Do not use it, unless you're *very* sure it's appropriate in context. It's super-easy to cause unintended offence. Especially if you're straight, I would *strongly* advise against using "Tunte". The queen in question may well punch you in the face -- or at least make a very cutting remark indeed.

Long story short and to answer your actual question: There is **no** situation whatsoever where a straight non-native speaker can use "Tunte" safely. A gay non-native speaker may be cut some slack, but it's still risky.